# Is it possible to hide HTML Elements?

Tags: javascript, html, swift, web-scraping, wkwebview

I´m trying to implement a highchart in a WKWebView. I successfully achieved to isolate the chart element out of the whole html. The problem is now, the chart lost it´s functionality. Is there a way to still load the whole page, but only showing the chart element?

Here´s the code:

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var webView = WKWebView()

    private var userContentController: WKUserContentController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.userContentController = userContentController
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
        view.addSubview(webView)
        self.webView = webView

        userContentController.removeAllUserScripts()

        // Is there a possibility to just hide all Elements except 'document.body.innerHTML'?
        // So the highchart will keep it´s functionality

        let script =
            "var selectedElement = document.querySelector('.panel-body');" +
        "document.body.innerHTML = selectedElement.innerHTML;"


        let userScript = WKUserScript(source: script,
                                      injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentEnd,
                                      forMainFrameOnly: true)

        userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.worldweatheronline.com/v2/weather-averages.aspx?locid=194044&root_id=192045&wc=local_weather&map=~/brussels-weather-averages/be.aspx")!
        webView.load(NSURLRequest(url: url as URL) as URLRequest)

   }
}
```

Link to the site: https://www.worldweatheronline.com/v2/weather-averages.aspx?locid=194044&root_id=192045&wc=local_weather&map=~/brussels-weather-averages/be.aspx

I´m trying this now for days, would be very glad to get some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store a reference to the DOM object that has the chart in it you should be able to clear the body's `innerHtml` and then append the chart. This will maintain all event listeners and chart functionality.

Here's the javascript you can inject:

```
var chartDiv = document.querySelector('.panel-body');
document.body.innerHTML = '';
document.body.append(chartDiv);
```

Alternatively, you could hide all the top level elements on the page and then append the chart to the body:

```
var chartDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.panel-body')[1];
document.querySelectorAll('body > *').forEach(function(el) { 
  el.style.display = 'none'; 
});
document.body.append(chartDiv);
```

Comment: This looks like  a very reasonable solution. I just tried: `let script =
        "var chartDiv = document.querySelector('.panel-body')" +
        "document.body.innerHTML = ''" +
        "document.body.append(chartDiv);"` But now it´s showing the whole page. Did I oversee something?

Comment: @JoschHazard I ran this js on the page in Chrome dev tools and it resulted in a page with only the chart being shown. You might need to delay the script injecting (or use WKWebView functionality for detecting load completion) on the page to ensure it fully loads before the injected script is executed.

Comment: @ JeremyPLease: I will definitely check this out.

Comment: @JoschHazard Actually, I just looked at the code in your comment. What you provided will result in a syntax error because you don't have line breaks or semicolons: Try: 
`let script = "var chartDiv = document.querySelector('.panel-body');" + "document.body.innerHTML = '';" + "document.body.append(chartDiv);"`

Comment: @ JeremyPLease: Before I really tried with with load completion: I´m wondering how it take too long to insert three lines of code in userContentController. The page is loaded just afterwards.

Comment: @ JeremyPLease: This is just a genuis solution Jeremy! You saved me days of wrong approaches. One last question if I may: Unfortunately for this question, I used an older exercise code. Why is the same method not working for https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/ ? Should be the same, right?

Comment: @ JeremyPLease: `let script = "var chartDiv = document.querySelectorAll('row.bottom-margin-1x')[1];" + "document.body.innerHTML = '';" + "document.body.append(chartDiv);"`

Comment: @JoschHazard Glad you like this solution. For your last comment, replace `'row.bottom-margin-1x'` with `'.row.bottom-margin-1x'`. Note that row is a class and needs to start with `.`.

Comment: @ JeremyPLease: I´m sorry, this was a failure in copying. But nevertheless, this isn´t the reason. It´s still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148826/discussion-between-jeremyplease-and-josch-hazard).

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to run scripts on your page? If so, insert jquery and a script section on your page then you can use the `hide()` function directly.

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#element_id_to_be_hidden').hide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @ leobelones: What do you mean with being allowed running scripts on "my" page? This isn´t my page.

Comment: @JoschHazard That's why I asked it. I imagined it was your company's page, and some companies don't allow adding scripts without some bureaucracy. Anyways, if you can then just do as I said and it should work.